# Fluttererror after fitebase connection

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have a really big problem after firebase and google sync

The app wont run and the error is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\Panda-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\shop_copy\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forWrapperPropertiesFile(WrapperExecutor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:60)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No value with key 'distributionUrl' specified in wrapper properties file 'C:\Users\Panda-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\shop_copy\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.reportMissingProperty(WrapperExecutor.java:156)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrlDeprecatedWay(WrapperExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.readDistroUrl(WrapperExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.prepareDistributionUri(WrapperExecutor.java:70)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.<init>(WrapperExecutor.java:57)
    ... 2 more
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleProfile failed with exit code 1
```

I run doctor it says no issue found.

I read a lot of forum posts already, but nothing.

Also, I did this tutorial: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlgRLf-MGDM&list=PLmnT6naTGy2SC82FMSCrvZNogg5T1H7iF&index=23

Answer (score 0):

@Matelevi12, seems like there is an issue with your **gradle-wrapper.properties** . Could your post your gradle-wrapper.properties from `C:\Users\Panda-PC\AndroidStudioProjects\shop_copy\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`? It should look something like this,

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

Comment: I add this 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
Its run without error, but after restaring i got this:

Comment: > Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
   > The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.5.0,16.5.0], [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
   > The library com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.1,16.0.1]], but resolves to 16.5.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: That was just an example. What does your dependencies in `android/app/build.gradle` look like?

Comment: dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

}

Comment: This is my only prbolem now!

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.1.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: Okay, my answer was just to give you an idea but if you want to use 4.10.2 then change your google-services version in android/build.gradle (in dependencies) to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`

Comment: Didn't help. I keep getting errors. Something reeally is wrong I cant fix this:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.1.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: You should really start fresh as there seems to be version mismatch. If you're just testing then you could try adding `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true` in android/app/build.gradle

Comment: I will start new but its seems like there is an error even with other fully wotking projects as well. Anyway thank you

Answer (score 0):

Browse to your project folder
Android < gradle < wrapper < gradle-wrapper.properties 
and make sure you have a distribution url specified for your gradle. If not specify it. Also you can copy the contents of gradle-wrapper.propeties file from another working project of yours and replace it with your current project.It won't affect your project.